# Magento 2 in Add to Cart page Remove item not working

Tags: magento2, addtocart, cart-items

Magento 2 in Add to Cart page Remove item not working.

After Login Add to Cart page Remove Item not working?

[image]

Comment: Is there any exception is throwing for remove item action?

Comment: no.. not use any exception

Comment: Enable developer mode, clear var/log, try to remove product from cart and check newly generated var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log to get clue on it.